# While loop to create multiple records in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm building an application where users can purchase tracking numbers. I have an Order model and an Order Transaction model. If the Order Transaction returns from the gateway with success, I'm using an after_save callback to trigger a method that creates the tracking numbers and inserts them into the database. Sometimes a user just orders one, but if they order more than one, I can't seem to get rails to create and insert more than one record.

Here's what I'm using -- I've never had to user a loop like this, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
def create_trackables
      if self.success == true
        @order = Order.find(order_id)
        @start = 0
        while @start < @order.total_tokens
          @trackable_token = Tracker.create_trackable_token
          @start += 1
          @trackable ||= Tracker.new(
            :user_id => @current_user,
            :token => @trackable_token,
            :order_id => order_id
            )
        @trackable.save 
        end
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

dmarkow is right that you should use `trackable` instead of `@trackable` but you also should be using `=` instead of `||=`.  You also might as well just use `create`.  Here's how I'd write it:

```
 def create_trackables
    return unless self.success
    order = Order.find(order_id) #you shouldn't need this line if it has_one :order
    1.upto(order.total_tokens) do
      Tracker.create!(
                     :user_id => @current_user,
                     :token => Tracker.create_trackable_token,
                     :order_id => order_id
                     )
    end
  end
```

Comment: Correct -- I completely missed that.

Comment: This is a bit late, but I newly discovered a magic tric to make creation fast. Do like this: "def create_trackables.... Tracker.transaction do  ...*code*... Tracker.create(something)... end

Comment: @Cort3z - if you want to do it fast, use activerecord-import

Answer (score 2):

Change `@trackable` to `trackable` to keep it scoped to the loop. Otherwise, the second time the loop runs, `@trackable` already has a value so the call to `Tracker.new` doesn't execute, and the `@trackable.save` line just keeps re-saving the same record. (Edit: Also remove the `||=` and just use `=`).

```
def create_trackables
  if self.success == true
    @order = Order.find(order_id)
    @start = 0
    while @start < @order.total_tokens
      @trackable_token = Tracker.create_trackable_token
      @start += 1
      trackable = Tracker.new(
        :user_id => @current_user,
        :token => @trackable_token,
        :order_id => order_id
        )
      trackable.save 
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It still seems to be saving only the one row ... I even changed the upper variable in the while statement to a number to test and I'm just getting one row out of it. Could `@start` be the problem?